# How to visualise relationship between categorical data and discrete data using python?

Tags: machine-learning, visualization

I have dataset with discrete values as well as categorical values and I want to find a relationship between them, like are they related at all. How do I visualise this using python? I read somewhere than I can use `boxplot` but `plt.boxplot` only accepts one data column. I am not sure how that works.

Comment: in this article you have some ways to do that with seaborn https://jmetzen.github.io/2015-01-29/ml_advice.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using seaborn. This is my source code for solving the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.swarmplot(x='Unmarried', y='Age', data=df)
plt.show()
```

where `Unmarried` and `Age` are the column names in the dataset `df`. This gave a plot which looks like this

[image]